# German quotation marks in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

How can I configure Sublime Text, so that instead of:

> "Hi there."

it writes

> „Hi there.“

I tried to look in the settings, but could not find the relevant option. Nor did I find a language package or something related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map key combination to insert your snippet.

Go to `Preferences -> Key Bindings` and on `Default.sublime-keymap - User` (right one) add:

> { "keys": ["alt+2"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "„$0“"} }

When you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> it will insert „“ with cursor in between the quotes.